# NextJS get one object from Json by ID

Tags: javascript, json, next.js

I am using NextJs in my project. How can I render one of the projects by ID?

```
{
  “projects”: [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "picture": "portf.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "picture": "portf.jpg",
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use find to go through the array and return a match

```js
const findId = 2
projects.find(element => {
 return element.id === findId
})
```

Check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find